# YII how to get number of rows affacted using queryRow Function

Tags: mysql, yii

In YII, to get single row i m using queryRow function

```
$SQL = //SQL QUERY

$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($SQL);
$result = $data->queryRow();

print_r(count($result));
```

print_r always shows 1 even if no data-set returned by query. i want if no data-set is returned it should show 0. so can call some other function

what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryRow` returns boolean `FALSE` or the first row. There is no count to be done here.

```
$row = $data->queryRow();

if ($row!==FALSE) {
   echo "I have results";
   print_r($row);
} else {
   echo "I don't have results";
}
```

If you want to get all rows you need to use `queryAll`